# What is this device attached to the seat-tube?

Tags: parts, vintage

[image: Photograph showing device attached to the seat-tube]

I dug out my late Dad's bicycle. Dad used the bicycle during his medical school days in the late 1940s ... or so. The bicycle has accumulated sufficient rust that it is impossible to identify the manufacturer.

What is this device attached to the seat-tube? It's upper portion appears to be spring-loaded..

Comment: My first thought was, "Duh! The lettering's as clear as day!" And then I read it and realised it was the camera's date stamp. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you sure the upper part has not been sliding down such that we can really take a clue from the distance between the two parts? I suspect that the two parts of the fixture are meant to hold an air pump with the upper part having come down.

On modern bikes the fixtures rely on a spring as part of the pump to secure it between the two pegs. It looks like here the fixture includes the spring to hold a pump that might not have been spring loaded.

Answer (score 24):

It appears to be a clamp-on pump peg that got moved down out of the way either intentionally or from coming loose.

Comment: My first feeling as well. It must have been farther apart and has been used to hold something. The distance from the bar makes only a bike pump likely.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I ran a google image search and one of the results that came up appear to be a close match... http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/p3YAAOSw42JWD8QZ/$_35.JPG

Never seen something like that mounted upon current bicycles here on the sub-continent though ...

Comment: The top thing should be further up. It's a pump-holder, used to have one of those. The top one is spring-loaded. You could pull it upwards, insert the pump and let go. It would clamp the pump firmly, which was required in the days of cobbled roads.